# Word for "parts of a plant"

Tags: nouns

Is there a word that means “plant part”?

As in, “member/organ is to body as ______ is to plant”.

Root, stalk, leaf, petal, stamen, are all what?

Comment: They are called "organs" as well. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Botany/Plant_structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**structure**  [wiki/botany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Botany/Plant_structure)

Plant morphology or **phytomorphology** is the study of the physical form and external **structure** of plants.  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_morphology)

As in:

> As in, “A member/organ is to the human body as a structure is to a
>   plant”.

and/or

Plant **organs** include the leaf, stem, root, and reproductive **structures**.

Meaning that plant parts can also be called **organs**!